Is it possible to retrieve Outlook emails via the Microsoft Graph API when using Azure B2C authentication
I’ve developed a Blazor Server application and successfully integrated Azure B2C authentication using user flows. Now, I’m working on connecting the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve Outlook emails for authenticated users. However, I’m encountering an issue where the Tenant ID is not found during the process.
If anyone has experience resolving this or insights into correctly obtaining the Tenant ID in this context, I’d appreciate your guidance. Thank you!
Need solution for connect graph api with a2b auth

Could you include more details like what you tried (code) and where you stuck by editing your question with code and error?


Note that: No, it is not possible to retrieve Outlook emails via the Microsoft Graph API when using Azure B2C authentication using user flows.


Using user flow, you cannot get access token to call Microsoft Graph API.
You can fetch access token only for the custom web API as scope.
Azure AD B2C application supports only uses offline_access and openid delegated permissions only.
And application type Mail.Read API permission do not support fetching of messages for outlook account

Hence as a workaround, you need to create Microsoft Entra ID application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)":

And grant Mail.Read API permission:

Note: To fetch the mails of personal Outlook account you need to make use of delegated flow or user interactive flow. Also make use of /me/messages endpoint.
Generate auth-code by using below endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&response_mode=query
&state=12345


Generated access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code


Now I am able to successfully fetch the outlook mails of user:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages


